# Xamarin Zxing Forms Mobile. System.NullReferenceException after changing Page orientation on Andorid

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, xamarin.forms, zxing.net

i've a question for you about Xamarin Zxing Forms library. I was playing with the ZxingScannerView object with his own method get and set bool IsScanning and IsAnalizing. On my custom overlay i've setted an option button which open a new page and i played to test it with his orientation device situation for every operation system, like Android or Ios.
Ios works very well, but for Android i've a problem about the camera device, when crashed my app into the NullReferenceException.

```
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

My code to set the page to view with navigation Page and set the scanner option are these

```
        scanner.IsAnalyzing = false;
        scanner.IsScanning = true;
        NavigationPage nav = new NavigationPage(new Page());
        Navigation.PushModalAsync(nav);
```

And also i've managed these with his override method on Appear and Disappear situation

```
protected override void OnAppearing()
    {
        base.OnAppearing();
        scanner.IsEnabled = false;
        scanner.IsAnalyzing = false;
        scanner.IsScanning = false;
    }

    protected override void OnDisappearing()
    {
        base.OnDisappearing();

        scanner.IsEnabled = true;
        scanner.IsAnalyzing = true;
        scanner.IsScanning = true;
    }
```

Anyone has got the solution about these problem?

Comment: I used `MainPage` with `MobileBarcodeScanner`, works fine, based on your code `NavigationPage nav = new NavigationPage(new Page());` and `Navigation.PushModalAsync(nav);`, it seems that you used a `NavigationPage` inside of another `NavigationPage`? Where're you using this code? Can you please show more code of your page?

Comment: No i've not use a NavigationPage inside another NavigationPage into my code project. The simple line of the Mainpage class is easy

    MainPage = new ScanPage();

and also the settings about my ZxingScannerView are these

    zxing = new ZXing.Net.Mobile.Forms.ZXingScannerView()
            {
                HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
                VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
                AutomationId = "zxingScannerView",
                Options = options
                
            };